Is a TARDIS a deprecated piece of Time Lord equipment?
Romana once brought up that TARDIS piloting courses were an elective, or were no longer offered at the Time Lord Academy, and even when the Time Lords were active, we didn't really see Time Lords use them to travel with, with nearly all of the TARDISes being owned by Rogue Time Lords, like the Master, who might well have stolen theirs like the Doctor did. The Time Lords seem to use things like Time Rings/trans-mats to get around, and as of "Hell Bent", both the other Time Lords and Rassilon seem to use a fighter-jet-like spacecraft, that doesn't appear to be a TARDIS (neither making the engine noise, nor appearing to fly/dematerialise like one).
The Doctor's TARDIS, famously, was a museum piece when they were young, something that both the TARDIS (as Idris in "The Doctor's Wife"), and the Doctor have mentioned.
Are TARDISes just deprecated pieces of tech, having been replaced by something newer?

"neither making the engine noise" That's not engine noise, that's from leaving the parking brake on.

@Acccumulation We've seen all the other TARDISes also make that noise, and they can't all have left the parking brakes on. Same for the House when he hijacked the TARDIS, and tried to break into the universe with it. If the engines were having enough trouble, it seems odd he'd keep the brakes on.

In a word, no. According to the prose novel Peacemaker, the Timelords armies were still constructing and using TARDISes (of varying kinds) right up to the end of the Great Time War, notably Battle TARDISes.

The sounds of the past thundered in his ears. The roaring of a million
Battle TARDISes. The screeching of a sky full of Dalek saucers.
The resounding drum of his own twin heartbeats as he made that most
terrible of choices.
You tried to exterminate the Daleks, but you failed! If only you had
been one with us then, we could have made their total destruction a
reality. . .
Regret weighed him down. ‘I did. . . what I had to.’

